# Eclipse not putting libraries in exported war file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, war

I am exporting my spring application as a war file. Apart from maven, there are few libraries added manually to classpath. When I export war they are not put in the .war file. How to put them there?

Comment: This question is answered here [Some necessary libraries are missing in war file after export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529690/some-necessary-libraries-are-missing-in-war-file-after-export-from-eclipse-why)

Answer (score 0):

If you build with Maven, every library needs to be referenced in the `pom.xml`. Then it is included into your final war.

Don't mix Eclipse classpath methods with Maven. If some artifacts are not in your repository, add them or reference a directory as additional Maven repository.

Comment: how can I reference a library in pom.xml if I dont know group id and artifact id? I've got only the jar files

Comment: Start using a repository manager and deploy them there first and use them as dependencies. If you have only the jar files check the MANIFEST.MF files in there and check if inside the jar `/META-INF/maven/`  folder exists? If yes there is a pom file inside the folder structure so you can get the correct groupId/artifactId/version etc.

Comment: can I simply add a folder as a maven repository to my pom?